# How do I close apps on my phone with Google Assistant?

Tags: samsung, android-10, google-assistant

I have an older Samsung A6 (model SM-A600T) with OneUI. I have also downloaded the latest version of Google Assistant on the same device. Many Google Assistant voice commands work as expected or fall back to understandable defaults.

However, I have not been able to find a way to close applications by voice. Attempting to directly close an application with Google Assistant leads to a prompt to specify the device name. I have tried "My Phone", "Samsung A6" and "SM–A600T" (the latter two under "About Phone" under Settings). None of those have seemed to work so far. I have also been unsuccessful in finding a voice command to bring up the "Recents" menu under OneUI.  This menu typically displays currently running apps and allows them to be closed individually or all at once.

For clarity, Google Assistant and the apps I wish to close all exist on the Samsung A6. Also, I do not have any other Google devices with Google Assistant.

Is there a way to close applications on the same device with Google Assistant?